# How to convert array of time to 24 hour format

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have a time array which holds slot time. I am trying to convert 12 hr format to 24 hr format but it is not working

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
let timeArray = ["11:12 AM", "11:13 AM", "1:14 PM"];
for (i in timeArray) {
  let [time, mod] = timeArray[i].split(" ");
  let [hr, min] = time.split(":");
  if (hr < 12) {
    hr = hr + 12;
  }
  console.log(hr);
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

The expected output should add 12 to hr number to convert it to 24 hr format.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use moment.js ( https://momentjs.com/ )
You can play with date and time object in numerous way you want by using moment.js

Answer (score -1):

Use parseInt to convert the string to an integer.

```js
let timeArray = ["11:12 AM", "11:13 AM", "1:14 PM"];
for (i in timeArray) {
  let [hr, min] = timeArray[i].split(":");
  if (hr < 12) {
    hr = parseInt(hr) + 12;
  }
  console.log(hr);
}
```

Comment: yes sir... thanks a lot

Comment: 11:12am is not 23:12